# Is there a bug when using keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy with RNN? Could you tell me how to find the correct prediction rate per word?

Tags: validation, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, prediction

Hallow,

I am working on an RNN for the Natural Language processing to predict the next word in sentences.
Recently, Recently, I have been confused to get a metrics of prediction accuracy with using keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy with SimpleRNN like:

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,  metrics=[keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=5)])

As a result, the following results were obtained.

Epoch 1/12
438/438 [==============================] - 40s 89ms/step - loss: 6.1173 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4646 - val_loss: 5.4228 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.5072 - lr: 0.0040
...

Thus, even in a very short training period, it achieved an accuracy of over 40%. However, when I examined the details of each prediction, the prediction was still poor.

[In this sentence, the success rate of the prediction was 0%.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKC2B.png)

The accuracy seems to be calculated as the probability of successful prediction of at least one word per sentence. But I think the probability of successful prediction per word makes more sense, so I need this one.

Consistent with this idea, when I increased the number of predicted words in a sentence from 8 (the first 8 words of the sentence) to 16, the accuracy improved dramatically, but each prediction was almost the same as the previous one (as above). This can be explained if one considers that the accuracy is calculated with a success rate of at least one success per sentence, and the more iterations of the prediction, the higher the probability of success per sentence.

Here are the codes which seem relevant:

```
##### building the model ######
def seq2vec_model_builder(HIDDEN_DIM):
  encoder_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(time_step, ), dtype='int32',)
  encoder_embedding = layers.Embedding(len(w_idx)+1, len(w_idx)+1, embeddings_initializer='identity', mask_zero=True, trainable=False)(encoder_inputs)

  encoder_RNN = layers.SimpleRNN(HIDDEN_DIM, return_state=True, name='sRNN',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')
  encoder_outputs, state_h = encoder_RNN(encoder_embedding)
  dense_layer = layers.Dense(len(w_idx)+1, 
                 bias_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.00001), activation='softmax')
  outputs = dense_layer(encoder_outputs)
  model = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, outputs)
  return model
 model = seq2vec_model_builder(HIDDEN_DIM=128)
```

```
 batch_size = 128;      
 def sample_generator(start, end):
 while True:
    for step in range((end - start) // batch_size):
        x, y = [],[]
        for line in range(batch_size):
            dataset = preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
                sents[start+step*batch_size+line],
                sents[start+step*batch_size+line],
                length=time_step,
                batch_size=1)
            for batch in dataset:
                X, Y = batch
                x.extend(X[0])
                y.extend(Y)
        x = np.reshape(x,((seq_length-time_step)*batch_size,time_step))
        y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, len(w_idx)+1)  
        yield x, y


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,  metrics=[keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=5)])

history_callback = model.fit(
  sample_generator(train_start, train_end),
  steps_per_epoch=(train_end - train_start) // batch_size,  
  validation_data=sample_generator(val_start, val_end),
  validation_steps=(val_end - val_start) // batch_size,
  initial_epoch=0,
  epochs=12,
  verbose=1 )
```

Could someone please tell me how to find the successful prediction rate per word?

Comment: Now, I consider this happened because  y_true contain a lot of 0. Those 0 are removed during training by mask_zero=True of layers.Embedding but may not be removed in model.fit.

Comment: `def my_top_k_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    values, y_ind = tf.nn.top_k(y_true, 1)
    values, top_k_pred = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, 5)
    to_top5 = tf.constant( [[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] , dtype=tf.int32 )
    input_y_for_top5 = tf.matmul( tf.reshape(y_ind,[-1, 1]) , to_top5 )
    correct_preds = tf.cast( tf.equal( input_y_for_top5 , top_k_pred ) , dtype=tf.float16)
    return tf.reduce_mean( tf.reduce_sum(correct_preds, axis=1))`  produced the same result as the built-in matric of TopKCategoricalAccuracy.